# Как запускаю сервис как BackgroundService?

Tags: c#, service

Хочу запустить BackgroundService как сервис, но все время получаю ошибку:

```
[SC] StartService: ошибка: 1053:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно.
```

Логи, как я понимаю, еще не успевают писаться. Не понимаю в чем дело

Пытаюсь запустить данный код:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseWindowsService().ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, config) => { }).UseWindowsService().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); });

public class Worker : BackgroundService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly AppConfig _appConfig;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger = null, AppConfig appConfig = null)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            //try
            //{
            //    await UpdateClient.StartTasks(_appConfig);
            //}catch(Exception e)
            //{
            //    _logger.LogError($"Error: {e.Message}");
            //}

            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);// 60000
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаю:

```
sc.exe create "UAService" binpath=*\UAService.exe 
sc start "UAService"
```

Конфиги

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\UpdaterApplication</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Какой тип приложения? Xamarin Android?

Comment: @aepot, Как обычную службу в WIndows.

Comment: Есть штатная рекомендация. В методе on start сервиса не должно выполняться никаких долгих вычислений - именно чтобы не получить ошибку "Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно" По шаблону делали? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#worker-service-template У меня работает webhost нормально по этому шаблону, только я тоже плюнул на powershell и инсталлирую сервис через sc.exe

Comment: @AK
Конфиги изменил:
И все заработало

Comment: Поле ответ находится ниже.